# this inside an async object method

Tags: javascript, async-await, this, babeljs, ecmascript-2017

I creating an object that uses async function methods with babel-polyfill/babel-preset-es2017, however I am having a problem with `this`:

```
let obj = () => {
    return {
        doAsync: async () => {
            let thing = await longProcess()
            return this.transform(thing)
        },

        transform: (thing) => {
            return psuedoCodeTransform(thing)
        }
    }
}

let instance = obj()
instance.doAsync()
// TypeError: cannot read property 'transform' of undefined`.
```

Is this something described in ES2017, a babel-polyfill/regeneratorRuntime gotcha?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `async`/`await` and everything with arrow functions.

Comment: ES7 !== ES2017 ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Arrow functions do not create their own context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this). They don't have their own `this` and `this` will refer to the enclosing scope's context. In this case (no pun intended), `this` does not refer to the same object as `instance` at all.

If you log `this` inside `doAsync`, you'll notice it's the `window` global.

Comment: Interesting. I am doing this inside an Angular service constructor, which gave me `console.log(this) // undefined`. That is what threw me off.

Answer (score 3):

Joseph the Dreamer's response is exactly right obviously, but since I work best by example, here is your code changed which should make it work. Notice the only change is actually defining `doAsync` as a normal function instead of arrow function:

```
let obj = () => {
    return {
        doAsync: async function() {
            let thing = await longProcess()
            return this.transform(thing)
        },

        transform: (thing) => {
            return psuedoCodeTransform(thing)
        }
    }
}

let instance = obj()
instance.doAsync()
// TypeError: cannot read property 'transform' of undefined`.
```

Comment: Or simply `async doAsync() { ... }`. I don't understand why someone wants to use arrow functions in object literals (unless for `this` of course). Method definitions are shorter.